# How can I keep my webservice in sync with an LDAP server?

Tags: web-services, ldap

I want to make a connection between an external LDAP server (e.g. Active Directory server) and my webservice. I want to make sure that a certain group of users from the LDAP server stays in sync with my webservice, e.g. when a user gets deleted from the LDAP server, the LDAP server should push this change to my webservice so the user can be deleted from my webservice as well.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Why not just use the LDAP server directly from the webservice?

Comment: You mean using the webservice as client of the LDAP server? I was thinking about that but I have no idea on how to implement it so the server can push the changes to the client. I'm new to LDAP and from what I understand, clients can only search, add, edit and remove, not register for updates and keep in sync. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Why would the webservice need to be pushed things like that? Surely you just want to lookup "is this user allowed" at login time or at the point they make other actions? Anyway I know nothing of Active Directory, but with OpenLDAP you could set yourself up to be a consumer of syncrepl information if you wanted. I assume AD has a similar mechanism. Worst case you could record the last date you synced and search based on the modification timestamps periodically.

Comment: To answer your questions, the contacts in the external LDAP server have to stay in sync with the contacts in my webservice. So whenever something changes in the LDAP server, the changes need to be pushed to the webservice so it can be updated.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is never store the contacts in the webservice. Always look them up from LDAP. LDAP is the one and only authoritative source of that information. Then there is no synchronisation issue at all. Use LDAP like you would any database service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments to your question indicate that you should retrieve data as required from the directory server instead of trying to maintain synchronization, with which I agree.

If synchronization is still your desire, you may be able to use [persistent search](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/mastering-persistent-search/), which notifies the connected client of changes in the database according to search parameters. Not all server support this mechanism, however.

#### see also

- [Persistent search in Java](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/mastering-persistent-search/)
- [LDAP: Persistent search](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-ldapext-psearch-03)